# How to parse xml webservice response using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, musicbrainz

I want to use following xml webservice.
[www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael jackson](http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael%20jackson)

which format is like below:

```
<metadata><artist-list offset="0" count="3418"><artist ext:score="100" type="Person" id="f27ec8db-af05-4f36-916e-3d57f91ecf5e"><name>Michael Jackson</name><sort-name>Jackson, Michael</sort-name><gender>male</gender><country>US</country>
```

I just want to parse this xml & get the gender from it .
I used following code to parse xml .
Here i get ext attribute of the artist but not working .

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael jackson',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
           // console.log(xml);
            $(xml).find('artist-list').each(function(){
            $(this).find('artist').each(function(){
                            var ext = $(this).attr('ext');
                            alert(ext);
                    });
            });
    }
```

});

Anybody can suggest me the example to parse xml using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: See my answer below. Any response would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael jackson',
    dataType: 'xml', 
    success: function(xml){ 
       $("artist", xml).each(function(){
           console.log($("gender", this).text());
       });
    }
});
```

**Update:**

Just checked the webservice and I saw that not every `artist` has a `gender` tag specified. In this case you can use the following:

```
    $("artist", xml).each(function(){
         var gender = $("gender", this);
         if(gender.length>0)
             console.log($(gender).text());
    });
```

See [JSFiddle Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RqFJh/)